# How to customize Themosis framework theme on wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Wordpress allows you to customize your themes from 
**Apperearance** --> **Customize**
I installed a **framework called Themosis**. It has it's own theme as well. However, just like any other themes on wordpress where you can edit/create forms/pages... I couldn't/wasn't able to do the same with Themosis.
Some who has used this theme can help me understanding, how we can customize from the wordpress instead of going to the page (opening resources/view/welcome.php to make and edit in there)?

Answer (score -1):

To customize a theme in themosis using the customizer which allows a person customize the look and feel of a page to his/her taste, themosis default theme is not connected to the wordpress customizer hence you will have to write code to get a custom look and feel like the one I have here.

[[image] <sup>Click for larger</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EQpZ.png)